# Read a text file to a variable in javascript without using XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, text-files

My javascript file is hosted in a cloud server and I would like to read a text file in the same directory as the js file to a variable in javascript without using XMLHttpRequest(). The code should be written entirely in javascript without using html. Is it possible to do that using javascript? if so how?

Comment: It is hosted in the same directory as the js file

Comment: It is a wso2 cloud app. The js is file is used by a jaggery file so I can't use  XMLHttpRequest()-it brings up a scriptException.

Comment: http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=file refer to this?

Comment: Not jaggery it is a js file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94272/discussion-between-olavi-sau-and-riyafa-abdul-hameed).

Comment: What extension is your file?

Comment: the file to read from is in .txt format